What is the exact translation of עד־עולם?
I was asking another question about how long Hashem's anger lasts and I saw some people were claiming that עד־עולם doesn't mean forever but rather until moshiach. What is the proper translation and how can we be sure that it is correct?

I see a Rashi to Isiah 32:14 that claims that its not forever in that context. Hard to tell when it applies in general though.
